# Pure JS detect click on wrapper and focus on inner input

Tags: javascript

I have responsive design, with padded container around input. Problem is, when user clicks in padded area, input wont be focused.

In jQuery the working code is:

```
$('.wrap').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).find('input').focus();
});
```

But can't seem to get it working in JS:

```
var elm_rows = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap");
elm_rows.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.getElementsByTagName("input").focus();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2f9sq3tf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing each of your `getElementsBy` functions as an array.

Example:

```
var elm_rows = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0];
elm_rows.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus();
});
```

To resolve the remaining concern just wrap this in a loop like:

```
var elm_rows = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap");
for (i in elm_rows) {
    elm = elm_rows[i];
    elm.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus();
    });
}
```

Could be better, but this works.

Comment: This will only add an event listener to the first element found whereas the jQuery code in the OP would add it to all elements

Comment: Right, but this is what he wanted afaik.

Comment: As Phil said. I updated the example: https://jsfiddle.net/dmueLtb1/3/ but even for first input, it didn't really do anything.

Comment: There was an additional error I forgot to change, `e` needs to be `this` in your click callback. (Edited the answer)

Comment: But yea this answer is shit, so go with a loop if you want jQuery like functions as mentioned.

Comment: Well, the answer is educational. Because I did saw the e vs. this issue myself too, but could not make it work never the less. So now the loop is missing, but first input does focus.

Comment: So, Im fairly bad at pure JS. But things should work in arrays right? So I should count the array with **.length** and then **for** loop it?

Comment: Yea that should work, I added a loop example if that helps you out too.

Comment: Pure oldschool JS. Works like a portal to 2000's. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
let wrap = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap');
wrap.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      // whatever you need to do goes here
    });
});
```

Comment: `NodeList.prototype` does not have `forEach()`.

Comment: Then what's this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it totally does, what it does not have is `filter` NodeList does not "inherit" from Array's prototype, but you can call any Array function on `NodeList` by using the `.call` method (i.e. `Array.prototype.map.call(NodeList, function(){})` )

Answer (score 1):

today you can use `querySelector` to find elements on the DOM (and inside some NODE too).

Example:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap');
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  els[i].addEventListener('click',function(ev){
    var input = ev.target.querySelector('input');
    if(input) input.focus();
  });
}
```

The `if` is required because with that code if you click on the `input` node, the event will propagate to the `.wrap` element, and your callback will execute too, but `ev.target` will be the `input` node and the query will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elm_rows = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap");
elm_rows[0].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.currentTarget.children[0].focus();
});
```

```css
.wrap {border: 3px solid blue; padding: 15px;}
input {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="text" name="" value="" />
</div>
```